# How to get the old value in hbase shell

Tags: hadoop, hbase

```
    hbase(main):004:0> create 'htable','cf'
0 row(s) in 0.4790 seconds

=> Hbase::Table - htable
hbase(main):005:0> alter 'htable', NAME => 'id', VERSIONS => 100
Updating all regions with the new schema...
0/1 regions updated.
1/1 regions updated.
Done.
0 row(s) in 2.2790 seconds

hbase(main):006:0> put 'htable','row1','cf:id',2
0 row(s) in 0.1560 seconds

hbase(main):007:0> put 'htable','row1','cf:id',4
0 row(s) in 0.0080 seconds

hbase(main):008:0> get 'htable', 'row1', {COLUMN => 'cf:id', VERSIONS => 4}
COLUMN                CELL                                                      
 cf:id                timestamp=1428041368763, value=4                          
1 row(s) in 0.0200 seconds
```

I altered the table by setting VERSIONS => 100 , but
every time it will give latest record. How to get the old value? Is there any addition commands or setting needs?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in hbase shell:

`disable 'htable'`

`drop 'htable'`

`create 'htable',NAME=>'cf',VERSIONS=>100`

`put 'htable','row1','cf:id',1`

`scan 'htable'`

`put 'htable','row1','cf:id',2`

`scan 'htable'`

`put 'htable','row1','cf:id',3`

`scan 'htable'`

`put 'htable','row1','cf:id',4`

`scan 'htable'`

`get 'htable', 'row1', {COLUMN => 'cf:id', VERSIONS => 4}`

`Scan` commands are to verify the and match timestamps.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I got the output when I give the versions=>100 at create table. but I can't drop the table. I want this on runtime, mean by altering the table. is it possible that I will get the version for next updated value after altering command?

Comment: You dont need to drop the table everytime. If you dont want to drop, start from the first `put` command. That will do. :)

Comment: you are not getting me, I already have table without enable versions. I altered the table by "alter 'htable', NAME => 'id', VERSIONS => 100
". then put the value on same row key. when I get the row I am getting only last value. check the updated question

Comment: The problem is with your `alter` command after `create` command. I too get the same problem by running your commands. Best way is to include `versions` in `create` command as i did. Using alter command returns only latest version of the value. (You have to create the table from scratch)